# MSAL.js - can't get token with desired scope

Tags: reactjs, typescript, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I'm using @azure/msal-browser v2.16.1 and @azure/msal-react v1.0.1 libraries for authentication and authorization using Azure Active Directory. My scenario is that a React frontend application acquires a token that is then used to authenticate in a backend .NET Core application and the frontend also calls Microsoft Graph API to read some data to display.

The frontend application is wrapped in following component:

```
type AuthWrapperProps = {
  pca: PublicClientApplication;
};

const AuthWrapper: React.FC<AuthWrapperProps> = (props) => {
  return (
    <MsalProvider instance={props.pca}>
      <MsalAuthenticationTemplate interactionType={InteractionType.Redirect} authenticationRequest={loginRequest}>
        {props.children}
      </MsalAuthenticationTemplate>
    </MsalProvider>
  );
};

// in another file:
export const loginRequest: RedirectRequest = {
  scopes: [`${msalConfig.auth.clientId}/.default`],
};

export const graphRequest: SilentRequest = {
  scopes: ["https://graph.microsoft.com/People.Read", "openid", "profile", "offline_access"],
};
```

And it works. I am able to acquire a valid token (audience is my registered Active Directory application) that I can successfully validate in the backend application.
The problem is that I can't use the same token to call Graph API (invalid audience). So I'm acquiring a new one before calling Graph API this way:

```
  async fetchGraph<T>(input: RequestInfo, init?: RequestInit): Promise<T> {
    const activeAccount = msalInstance.getActiveAccount();
    return msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent({ ...graphRequest, account: activeAccount! }).then((tokenResponse) => {
      return fetch(`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/people`, { ...init, ...this.authorizationHeader(tokenResponse.accessToken) }).then(
        async (resp) => {
          if (resp.ok) {
            return resp.json();
          }
        }
      );
    });
  }
```

And in the response I got

```
code: "ErrorAccessDenied"
message: "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again."
```

I've checked the access token that I've got from `acquireTokenSilent` and the scope is
[image: token scope]
so it seems that my requested scope from `graphRequest` is ignored and some default values are requested instead and that's why I can't access `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/people`. But in my application registration I've chosen this permission
[image: App permissions].
What can I do to get a token with scope that I request?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the scope is not being recognized because of the URL format you are using. As you can see from the API/Permissions name column, the other Graph scopes are being returned when added without the Graph resource URL.

Try using `"People.Read"` instead of `"https://graph.microsoft.com/People.Read"` and see if the scope comes back in the access token.